# Is there an ASP.NET WebControl for the <p> tag?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, asp.net-webcontrol

Simple question, difficult to search for (due to the main part of the question being the single letter `p`)!

In ASP.NET, `<asp:Panel/>` is rendered as a `<div></div>` block, `<asp:Label/>` is rendered as a `<span></span>` block... is there one that renders as `<p></p>` block?

It doesn't look like it from [MSDN for the WebControl class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#inheritanceContinued), but I thought I would ask in case I've missed something obvious.

(I realise the obvious solution is to just use `<p runat="server" id="p1"></p>` and use the generic html control class)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, there is no built-in control specifically for `<p>`. A `LiteralControl` or the `<p runat="server" />` version you gave are the closest you will get.

You could always *create* your own control, though. You can create a class that implements `WebControl`, and override the `Render` method:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
{
   output.WriteFullBeginTag("p");
   output.Write(this.Text);
   output.WriteEndTag("p");
}
```

There are more instructions on how to write your own server controls here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366537(v=vs.100).aspx

And a list of all of the .NET web and server controls here:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306459

Comment: Thanks Cory, that is as I expected... I was hoping for a `doh` moment as somebody pointed me at the all-too-obvious class that I'd missed.  Once I get my 6 months off to do whatever work I want to do myself, I'll get around to creating one `</dream>`  ;-)

Comment: The thing is that if you override the Render() method, you will have to take care of all of the rendering yourself. If you do it using the approach I mentioned here, the control will render just as you would expect from a Label, only with the p tag instead.

Answer (score 6):

I've had exactly the same issue. After I started to use a similar technique Cory uses here, I found an even easier one, that basically does the same and solves your issues. However, it has one benefit when compared with the solution above: you don't have to render the whole control yourself.

Basically all you need to do is the following:

- Create you own control, inherit e.g. from the Label control.
- Override the `RenderBeginTag()` method.
- Write your own tag, e.g. `p`.
- The end tag will be written automatically.
- Your new tag will now replace the default tag (`span` in this example).

See code below:

```
    public class P : Label
    {
        public override void RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            writer.RenderBeginTag("p");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have added this line at the top of the method, to include the CssClass attribute: `writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, this.CssClass);`

Comment: Instead of overriding the `RenderBeginTag()` method, you can also override the `TagKey` property: `protected override HtmlTextWriterTag TagKey => HtmlTextWriterTag.P;`

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no special class for `<p>` element, you can use `HtmlGenericControl` to generate `<p>` tag like this:

```
var p = new HtmlGenericControl("p");
```